# How to check test run results in nose2?

Tags: python, nose2

With `unittest` I can check if there were failed tests during test run like this:

```
import unittest

all_tests = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('path-to-tests')
results = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(all_tests)
if results.wasSuccessful():
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

How to do the same with `nose2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer.

```
import nose2

test_run = nose2.discover(argv = ['-s', 'path-to-tests'], exit = False)
if test_run.result.wasSuccessful():
    do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```